# Is there any way to force laptop with two graphics cards to use the better one?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have an MSI laptop with an additional monitor and two graphics cards: an motherboard-integrated Intel HD Graphics 4600 and a separate Nvidia GTX 870M.  I'd like to run the monitor on 1600x1200 resolution, but I can't, even though the Nvidia graphics card *should* be powerful enough to handle it.  No matter what I do, the Windows screen resolution dialog limits me to 1200x1024 (and there aren't even any resolution options in the settings in the Nvidia control panel).

I've tried everything I can to force the laptop to use the Nvidia card (disabling/uninstalling the drivers for the Intel one, changing every setting known to man, etc.), with no luck.  From what I have read on the internet, it seems this is because laptops *always* use the integrated graphics initially, and will only a secondary card to run specific graphics-intensive applications.

Because of this, it would seem that I will never be able to run any resolution higher than 1280x1024 on my monitor.  My question, ideally for someone who knows more about laptop graphics than I do, is: am I misunderstanding anything, and if not is there any workaround that would allow me to run my second monitor at a higher resolution?

Comment: What is the model of your nvidia card?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question with both the Intel and Nvidia card models.

Comment: The reason is probably not because you are using built-in instead of nVidia card.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but if that's not the problem then I really have no idea what is going on.  The reason I was thinking the built-in card was the problem was that I've tried both disabling and uninstalling the native graphics card drivers, but my computer still uses that card (with some sort of generic drivers) instead of the Nvidia one.  Thus it *seems* like my computer is refusing to use the Nvidia card to drive my normal usage, and only using it when I play 3D games.